# How can i Change background color on scroll?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

I want to change background color of my navbar section on scroll, I could try but its never work.

My code here.

```
const [colorChange, setColorChange]=useState(false)
 
 const changeColor=()=>{
   if(window.scrollY >=120){
     setColorChange(true)
   }
   else{
     setColorChange(false)
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's the whole code you have then it seems  that `changeColor` method is never executed. You have to bind it with `onScroll` event